# Retry policy using Azure Redis Cache

Tags: c#, caching, azure, azure-redis-cache

Recently we moved from Azure In-Role Caching to Azure Redis Cache (that is being consumed by Azure Web Sites).

I am now in process of reviewing code and one line caught my eye.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling;

// CODE

_retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<CacheTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

// CODE

_retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => dataCache.StringGet(fullCacheKey));
```

Does RetryPolicy from TransientFaultHandling assembly make sense for Redis Cache? Or is this a code that actually has no purpose anymore as we are using Azure Redis instead of In-Role caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to pick it up as suspect, the `CacheTransientErrorDetectionStrategy` is built specifically for Windows Azure Caching.

http://www.projky.com/entlib/6.0/Microsoft/Practices/EnterpriseLibrary/TransientFaultHandling/CacheTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.cs.html

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides the transient error detection logic that can recognize transient faults when dealing with Windows Azure Caching.
/// </summary>
```

You could keep the RetryPolicy but you would need to replace the error detection strategy with your own implementation of `ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy`, for example to detect timeout exceptions.

Comment: Hey, cheers, that's exactly I was going after. Redis is throwing TimeoutException that was not being caught by CacheTransientErrorDetectionStrategy. Implementing it by myself should do the trick. Thanks bunch.

Comment: Hi Jakub, We are also facing similar intermittent TimeOut issue. Is this recommend to retry in such cases!

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. You can reuse the RetryPolicy logic

Comment: Could you please let me know on what you base this statement? Have you seen it being anywhere described?

Comment: Hi Pravav, We are also facing similar intermittent TimeOut issue. Is this recommend to retry in such cases